# How to print after the first loop in a 2d array

Tags: python

I’m trying to write a function for printing a 2d array, however, I couldn’t insert the `print()` function after the first loop.

Here is the code I tried:

```
def multitaple(n):
    [print(i*j,end=" ") for i in range(1,n+1) for j in range(1,11)]
```

And here’s how the code would look like if I used nested loops:

```
def multitaple(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,11):
            print(i*j, end=" ")
        print(end=("\n")) # this is the print function I want to insert in the 2d array
```

How could I get that extra `print` in the first version of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable expression for the `end` argument, like this:

```
def multitaple(n):
    [print(i * j, end=" " if j < 10 else "\n") 
        for i in range(1,n+1)
        for j in range(1,11)]
```

However, it is not such good practice to call a function with side effects (such as `print`) in a list comprehension.

It is better to not call `print` at all, and instead return a string that can be printed by the caller:

```
def multitaple(n):
    return "\n".join([
        " ".join(map(str, range(i, i*10+1, i)))
            for i in range(1,n+1)
    ])

print(multitaple(3))
```